# Compare two dates in different formats in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-comparison, gettime

I'm trying to compare two dates in different formats to highlight new items added from last visit but there is one problem with first date:

```
jQuery( "td.details > span:last-child" ).each(function() {
  var a = jQuery( this ).text();
  var b = a.split('/');
  var c = b[1]+'/'+e[0]+'/'+e[2]; //dd.mm.yyyy=>mm.dd.yyyy
  var d = new Date( c );
  var date = d.getTime();

    jQuery('<span/>', {
    'class':'date',
    'text': date,
    }) .appendTo( "td.details > p" );
});
```

HTML:

```
    <td class="details"><p>new item1</p><span>10/1/2017 17:06</span></td>
    <td class="details"><p>new item2</p><span>09/1/2017 22:26</span></td>
    <td class="details"><p>new item3</p><span>09/1/2017 11:18</span></td>
    <td class="details"><p>new item4</p><span>08/1/2017 14:32</span></td>
```

Every `td` have different date, expectation is in every `td` will be created `span` with appropriate `d.getTime()` value (just testing), but newly created `span` contains all `d.getTime() values` (from every `td`) not only that one. What am I doing wrong?

Second date will be same(lastvisit) for every `td` so no problem

Comment: `.appendTo( "td.details > p" );` says, "append to all p in all td.details".  You need to scope this to the current one.  At a guess, this might work (hence comment not answer): .`appendTo($(this).closest("td").find(".details > p"));`.

Comment: did not work, but `.appendTo(this)` works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work better?

```
jQuery('<span/>', {
  'class':'date',
  'text': date,
}).after(this);
```

In your code you are appending `date` to every `td.details > p` not only the current one. `.after()` will add the  after the your last span inside td

Comment: oh, "this" little thing. Thank you! **edit:** .after did not work, .appendTo works fine